# Caching data with Tomcat server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7

I have problem about Tomcat Server and MySQL server.

Sometime data can not get form Mysql server . All though database have many data.
When I shutdown Tomcat server and the Startup tomcat server . Everything become a normally. 
I think maybe reason is Caching of Tomcat server but I am not sure.

If you know that please explain for me.

Thanks

Comment: How do you know that it's Tomcat, and not your application, who is "caching" information from your database?

Comment: it is your app which is responsible for caching. Tomcat dont have much to do with db connections and db caching.

Comment: Because I do not　anything with MySQL . I have only restart Tomcat server. And then I can get data on the screen.

Comment: Sounds like a resource leak to me. How are you managing your DB connections? Do you remember to always `close()` them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat may be creating connection pool to your database. And may be your application not closing connection to database after use. If this is the case then after some database operation you cant connect to your database from your application. Check your application is closing connection to database. Restarting tomcat will close connection to database from your application. Restarting tomcat is not the solution. Make sure your application is closing connection to database after use

Comment: Thanks ! I will to check it now